# Open an external page in a jQuery Colorbox

Tags: jquery, colorbox

How can I open a jQuery colorbox with an external site loaded. I have tried:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery.colorbox({ href:"http://www.google.com", iframe: true });
});
```

But with no success. I have not been able to find an example of this from either the colorbox-site or SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you want the colorbox to open on the load of your page.

If yes You need to write.

`jQuery.fn.colorbox` instead of just `jQuery.colorbox.`

also specifcy width and height elements for your colorbox iframe.

http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/core/example1/index.html is having an example in Other Content Types section

Comment: I forgot to specify the height and width, and then it worked. Why should I use jQuery.fn.colorbox instead of jQuery.colorbox?

Comment: You do not need the ".fn" string; the colorbox developer Jack Moore has thoughtfully taken care of that.  Height and Width are always required for iFramed content.